# Query about how to block any PHP cURL request

Tags: php, curl

I am making  a curl request to my website...and it's giving response.But when I am try to access website like www.hotstar.com, it's not giving the content. So my question is how to block any curl request, through any header.

Comment: You can never truly block _all_ curl requests (curl simply makes a request, just like any browser does), but you could make sure that the request to your site has a "user agent" header. However, if someone simply adds a user agent header to their curl request, they will get content.

Comment: use **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**

Comment: @Dave That has no effect on cURL requests.

Comment: yes but when i am doing curl request to say http://www.hotstar.com its showing copied to clipboard. How?